# $5$-dimensional space of $\mathbb R^6$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Problem from Strang:
Suppose $S$ is a $5$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^6$. True or false (example if false):
(a) Every basis for S can be extended to a basis for $\mathbb R^6$ by adding one more vector.

The correct answer for this question is shown to be true. But what if we add zero vector? It "kills" linear independence and hence the vectors can't be a basis. Why I'm wrong?

Comment: The statement has a hidden quantifier (it's hidden in the word "can"): it means that there exists another vector you can add to get a basis, not that every vector can be added to get a basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is asking can you find some vector such that when you add it to a basis of $S$,   it becomes a basis for $\mathbb{R}^6$?

It does not mean that adding any vector works.

Comment: Thank you guys. It seems that I missed that key word "can".

Answer (score 1):

It is true because you only need to add one vector to produce a basis for $\mathbb{R}^6$. It doesn't say adding any vector will produce a basis.